# Losing Materials Blender 2.80 to GLTF 2.0 export using Khronos Group Add On

Tags: blender

I am exporting models from Bender 2.8 to GLTF 2.0 and losing materials that I worked hard on to get right in Blender. What is the next step for me to try? Redo stuff with GLTF shaders from Khronos group?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the doc here?
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html

It will be difficult to answer without knowing what is your node setup, so don't hesitate to share it. 
If you think something is wrong, don't hesitate to open an issue here:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO

Comment: Hi Julien. Thank you so much for your response. Again, I am away from my project right now. Yes, I am familiar with this document. I have been doing blender for less than 3 months and I had not foreseen this type of stuff prior to me trying exporting to gltf format. Let me read through this in detail and respond again. Thanks again Julien.